# Back to back update in a same column of table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to update two rows of a same column in a table named tbl_sub_categories with different where and i did this:

```
$temp = 4;
$sub_cid = 100;
$rank = 6;
$next_id = 112;

$this->change_rank($temp, $sub_cid);
$this->change_rank($rank, $next_id);

function change_rank($rank,$sub_cid){
//    echo $rank.'--'.$sub_cid.'-------';
    $query  = "UPDATE tbl_sub_categories SET fld_rank = '".$rank."' WHERE fld_id ='".$sub_cid."'";
    $this->db->query($query);
}
```

while updating the tbl it only updates first row butnthe next row doesnt change... i am not understanding why is this so.. Please help...

Comment: What?That query only updates the row(s) where fld_id is whatever you set it.Whats the problem?

Comment: try to change name of variable used in function.

Comment: @ButaniVijay: ya i tired that but nothing happens

Comment: @Mihai: thi problem is the update is only once done.

Comment: have you also update variable name in query.

Comment: @ButaniVijay ya i had done so

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CodeIgniter, there's a feature in its Active Record class to update multiple rows:

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'fld_rank' => '4',
      'fld_id' => '100'
   ),
   array(
      'fld_rank' => '6',
      'fld_id' => '112'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('tbl_sub_categories', $data, 'fld_id');
```

Take a look at `$this->db->update_batch();` method in CI [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#update).

Comment: ya im using ci. the problem is same, but if i change the fld_rank to next column name then it works

Comment: What do you mean by `change the fld_rank to next column name`? which column? You're updating only the `fld_rank` column. `fld_id` contains the where key.

Comment: ya im updating fld_rank but i have another coloumn too like fld_category and if i change the fld_category then it changes the value of fld_cateogory but when i again try to change the fld_rank column no any changes occurs

Answer (score 0):

This may be work ->change your function as below:

```
function change_rank($rank1,$sub_cid1){
//    echo $rank.'--'.$sub_cid.'-------';
    $query  = "UPDATE tbl_sub_categories SET fld_rank = '".$rank1."' WHERE fld_id ='".$sub_cid1."'";
    $this->db->query($query);
}
```